# Accidentally deleted my User class in Parse.com and now can't sign up

Tags: android, parse-platform

Now, whenever I try to sign up from the sign up screen in my Android app, I just get the `AlertDialog: "Oops! invalid session token"` (which is the Parse exception e).

Its not a problem with my code because I had just tested and signed up successfully right before I accidentally deleted the User class in `Parse.com` data browser.
Here is the code to the `AlertDialog` in case its needed to solve the problem:

```
newUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
@Override
public void done(ParseException e) {
    if (e == null){ 
        Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, MainActivity.class); 
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    } 
    else {  
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUpActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage(e.getMessage()); 
        builder.setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Its an old cookie probably.  Can you delete anything cached for your app and retry?

Comment: how do i delete the cached stuff?

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: oh I thought you meant clearing the cache in the app.  let me go clear my browser (Chrome) cache.

Comment: cleared it, still not working.

Comment: Try to recreate User class on Parse.com

Comment: how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my own question. I thought it could be a problem with the emulator, so I ran it in the emulator that comes with android studio instead of genymotion and it worked! 
Then I went and created another genymotion emulator and ran it and it worked. So problem solved.

But I still don't know where problem is, maybe the emulator cache? (but I closed and restarted the emulator a bunch of times)